# ScrapingHub: No Module named Mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapinghub

In my local machine everything works fine, but when I deployed it on ScrapingHub I've got an error saying all "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector".

All I need is to, whenever I run my spider or run through job schedule it will automatically add all the scraped items through my database.

Also I am trying to use item API if I don't have a choice to solve this issue

Please help thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the MySQL client lib to allow your code to communicate with a MySQL server. I'd suggest you to create a `requirements.txt` file, in order to install required dependencies on ScrapyCloud.

You should create your `requirements.txt` on the base dir of your project with the following content:

```
mysql-connector
```

And then your scrapinghub.yml file:

```
projects:
  default: 12345
requirements:
  file: requirements.txt
```

Note: If this file doesnt exist, you might need to run `shub deploy` once to generate it.

You can get more information about how to install dependencies on SC on this link
https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200400-deploying-python-dependencies-for-your-projects-in-scrapy-cloud

It's important to note that you must point your configuration to a running MySQL server, since there is no MySQL server running on SC.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear. You are trying to scrape some data and to store it into a MySQL database. In order to do it, you need to be able to connect to MySQL, so, on your server you will need to install MySQL if you have not done so already and the connector to MySQL.

This command installs the connector for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-mysql.connector
```

If you have some other brand of Linux as your server, then the command might be different.

Comment: Hi @lajos Arpad, I am already done on that part in my local machine, It's working fine on my end, but when I deploy it on server which is ScrapingHub I got that error.

Comment: @ChristianRead you need to do that on the server as well. Installing the connector on your local machine will not install it on the server.

Comment: Yes @lajos Arpad I am trying that already but no luck any suggestion that you could give please?

Comment: @ChristianRead of course, but first of all, please explain what operating system do you have on your server and how are your attempts failing, possibly an error message could help.